# Dart pub global run can't resolve script name

Tags: dart

I have a simple dart project that has one executable in bin folder (test.dart). I have activated it with dart global activate and now I can run it directly with just typing the name of that executable file.

Inside that dart file I would like to know the path of that script. Basically for now I'm just printing something like this:

```
print('1: ' + Platform.script.toString());
print('2: ' + Platform.script.path);
print('3: ' + Platform.executable);
print('4: ' + Platform.packageRoot);
print('5: ' + Platform.resolvedExecutable);
```

When I run it directly:

```
test
```

or with pub:

```
pub global run test
```

or even with package name:

```
pub global run test:test
```

I always get the same result:

```
1: http://localhost:53783/test.dart
2: /test.dart
3: E:\apps\dart-sdk\bin\dart
4:
5: E:\apps\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe
```

The issue here is that I can't get the absolute path for test.dart file.

When I run it like this:

```
dart /path/to/project/bin/test.dart
```

I get what I need:

```
1: file:///E:/projects/dart/test/bin/test.dart
2: /E:/projects/dart/test/bin/test.dart
3: dart
4:
5: E:\apps\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe
```

Is there a way how to get absolute path for a script that is currently running, regardless of a way how it was executed?

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr:** There's not a great way of doing what you want, but it's in the works.

The notion of a "path for a script that is currently running" is more complicated than it might sound at first blush. There are a number of ways that the Dart ecosystem invokes `main()`. Off the top of my head, here are a few:

- Manually running the file with `dart`.
- Running the file in an isolate.
- Compiling the file to a snapshot and either manually running it or running it in an isolate.
- Automatically compiling the file to a cached executable and running that either in a subprocess or in an isolate.
- Adding a wrapper script that imports the file and invokes `main()`, and either running that in a subprocess or in an isolate.
- Serving the file over HTTP, and running it either in a subprocess or in an isolate.

In some of these cases, the "script that is running" is actually a wrapper, not the original file you authored. In others, it's a snapshot that may have no inherent knowledge of the file from which it was created. In others, the file has been modified by transformers and the actual Dart code that's running isn't on disk at all.

I suspect what you're actually looking for isn't the executable URL itself, but the location of your package's files. We're working on a collection of APIs that will make this possible, as well as a [`resource`](https://github.com/dart-lang/resource) package that will provide a nice API for dealing with your packages' resources.

Until that lands, there is a `dart:mirrors` hack you can use. If you give one of your library files an explicit library tag, say `library my.cool.package`, you can write:

```
var libPath = currentMirrorSystem().findLibrary(#my.cool.package).uri.path;
```

This will give you the path to your library, which you can use to figure out where your package's `lib/` files live.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation! I tried proposed solution but I can only get relative path which in my case is not enough. To be more exact, you can take a look at the code here: https://github.com/Medianova/project_builder
The idea is to copy template files and folders to some other location and I can't do that if I don't know the path to template files.Relative location doesn't help me in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a reliable way to access the current file while running in `pub` you'll need to use mirrors.

Here's a sample usage with `dartdoc` tests - https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc/blob/41a5e4d3f6e0084a9bc2af80546da331789f410d/test/compare_output_test.dart#L17

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

Uri get _currentFileUri =>
    (reflect(main) as ClosureMirror).function.location.sourceUri;

void main() { ... }
```

Not particularly pretty, but it's easy to just put into a util file.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/blob/154fecd4b686da2ca9a27166a9b17b599c0bf018/test/utils.dart#L24

Comment: Thanks for help, but this only gets me a relative path, which in my case is not enough.